# jQuery Automatic Thumbnail Scroll Script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, carousel

Is there a jQuery Script that does something along the lines of this:

http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/SliderGallery/

*Note: You have to click on a location to understand what I am asking of.*

Except for having the Lightbox and the Scrollbar. Instead of it manually rotates the images? A Carousel per se?

Something in which I can have a number of images that rotate in a specified area with a specified width?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up answering my own question and finding a Script similar to what I asked.

If anyone runs into this same issue... View these links:

http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/
http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jCarouselLite

Thanks